# SSIS: Making an Informix transaction local doesn't work

Tags: ssis, informix

For a single SSIS task I'm trying to make its transaction local.
To simplify things, I'm trying to do it like this:

- create the new package
- create just one Execute SQL Task
- inside that task I delete some rows from destination table and issue a ROLLBACK:

  `DELETE FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE SOME_COLUMN = 'ABCD';`

  `ROLLBACK;`
- I create a new Connection Manager for that task (IBM Informix OLE DB Provider)  and make sure it passes `Test Connection`
- after adding the task, I change its `TransactionOption` property to `Required`
- after that, I change the `RetainSameConnection` property of Connection Manager to `True`

As I understand, the task should start a local transaction without using DTC. However, this is the output when I run the package:

> SSIS package "Package1.dtsx" starting.
>
> Information: 0x4001100A at ROLLBACK: Starting distributed transaction
>   for this container.
>
> Error: 0xC001402C at Package1, Connection manager
>   "xxx@yyy": The SSIS Runtime has failed to
>   enlist the OLE DB connection in a distributed transaction with error
>   0x8004D01B "The Transaction Manager is not available.".
>
> Error: 0xC0202009 at Package1, Connection manager
>   "xxx@yyy": SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. 
>   An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x8004D01B.
>
> Error: 0xC00291EC at ROLLBACK, Execute SQL Task: Failed to acquire
>   connection "xxx@yyy". Connection may not be
>   configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this
>   connection.
>
> Task failed: ROLLBACK
>
> Information: 0x4001100C at ROLLBACK: Aborting the current distributed
>   transaction.
>
> Warning: 0x80019002 at Package1: SSIS Warning Code
>   DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but
>   the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1);
>   resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches
>   the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the
>   MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors. SSIS package "Package1.dtsx"
>   finished: Failure.

Does anyone know what's happening here?

Comment: some help http://richardlees.blogspot.com/2010/01/transaction-manager-is-not-available.html

Comment: @Justin: considering this problem, this article doesn't have enough/right information. For example, see [this](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/08/20/SSIS-Nugget_3A00_-RetainSameConnection-property-of-the-OLE-DB-Connection-Manager.aspx).

Comment: @OzrenTkalcecKrznaric Have you tried adding `BEGIN` or `BEGIN WORK;` as I can see you are trying to rollback a transaction without actually starting one.

Comment: your article quite old, maybe something changed in SSIS. I think maybe problem is that you set `TransactionOption` property to `Required`, just leave to supported if you want to do rollback with your own sql code

Comment: @Peter_R: If I start transaction in SQL as you propose, SSIS can use it only in that task. However, if I let SSIS start the transaction (please read about TransactionOption/Required option), I can use it across several tasks.

Comment: @Justin: I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 version. Properties in question work the same. If I don't use TransactionOption property (leave it as Supported), how can I issue a local transaction across multiple tasks?

Comment: @OzrenTkalcecKrznaric Not true SSIS can use it across multiple tasks as long as the `RetainSameConnection` is used. The article explains it exactly, although it doesn't use an Informix connection, that might be the issue here.

Comment: @Peter_R Obviously I was wrong. However, it doesn't matter whether I start the transaction or SSIS - same thing happens. Just tried with three tasks - Task1 BEGIN, Task2 DELETE ... , Task3 ROLLBACK. Same error, same message.

Comment: try do that sql code direct in informix if this works maybe is something with informix DB and ssis communication, and you need to use DTC (Informix DB is in other physical server)... interesting problem

Comment: @Justin: directly in Informix it works. Informix DB indeed is on a different server than dtsx (which is on my PC), but I don't see why is there a need for DTC? E.g. MSSQL doesn't need it for that same configuration.